# How do I run a service at a specific time in SailsJS

Tags: javascript, service, sails.js

I'm looking for a way to fire a service at a specific time in SailsJS. In this case, I have an `Event` **model** which includes two attributes: a `boolean` which is default to be **false** and a `datetime` which is assigned whenever an event is created. Also, there is an `endEvent` service to be fired according to the `datetime`.

I want my whole process be like, for every created event:

1. Initialize the `boolean` attribute to **false**.
2. Set the `datetime` into a future time.
3. Run the service according to the `datetime` which set the `boolean` attribute from **false** to **true**.

My model:

```js
// Event.js
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    end: {
      type: 'boolean'
    },
    deadline: {
      type: 'datetime'
    }
  }
}
```

My service:

```js
// endEvent.js
module.exports = {

  setEnd: function(event) {
    Event.findOne(event).exec(function (err, result) {
      result.end = true;
      result.save();
    });
  }
};
```

However I cannot find the proper way to run a service in a specific time.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sailsjs` has no support for task scheduling out of the box. You will have to use a package like [`node-cron`](http://merencia.com/node-cron/) or [`agenda`](https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda) or [`kue`](https://github.com/Automattic/kue) and build your own solution. Also, there is a sails hook, [`sails-hook-schedule`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-schedule) which you can try out.